# Stop propagation of a virtual method in child class

Tags: c++

I have a main class, "A", and two child class "B" and "C", with some methods

```
Class A
{
    virtual bool method1() const = 0;
    virtual void method2(int) = 0;
}

Class B : public A
{
    bool method1() const;
}

Class C : public A
{
    void method2(int);
}
```

But when i try to declare a new B object, my compiler say me "cannot instantiate abstract class, pure virtual function A::method2 has nos overrider". Is there a way to fix that ?

Comment: Yes, you need to define a `method2` override in `B`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Like that ? `void method1() const override;`

Comment: All instantiable classes need to implement all pure functions or have bases do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By putting `= 0` at the end of a virtual method declaration you are making it pure virtual. Thus you are telling the compiler that no implementation is provided in the base class and that any derived classes *must* provide one. Since your derived class `B` doesn't implement `method2` you get that error message. The compiler is doing exactly what you told it to.

If you don't actually want to force all derived classes to implement a virtual function, then you shouldn't make is pure virtual. So you would remove the `= 0` and provide some kind of default implementation in the base class. Depending on your design, this could as simple as `virtual void method2(int) { }`

Otherwise, the derived classes must implement *all* pure virtual methods. So in the code you've posted, `B` and `C` each need to implement both `method1` and `method2`.

Comment: Thank you ! `virtual void method2(int) { }` is excatly what i need.